# What is an alternative in Feijoada to smoked ham or beef?

Tags: substitutions, beef, ham

While smoked ham and beef are great, are there alternative ingredients that can still impart the 'smoked' flavoring?

Comment: See:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-can-we-make-substitution-questions-more-helpful   You might want to provide some context on *why* you wish to substitute, and what limitations or constraints you have.   Otherwise, the trivial answer is "liquid smoke."

Comment: What kind of answer is "liquid smoke"?  Use a little common sense and/or cognitive ability - looking for a subsitute that is a carbon based food, not liquid.  You know, I left this site 2 years ago because of nonsense like this and I see it hasn't gotten any better!!  Holy Crap

Comment: Actually, it is quite a serious answer, and I am sorry you didn't like it.   Liquid smoke is quite literally condensed smoke from burning wood, hickory if I recall correctly.  If you would give some more context, you will get better answers.  Check my profile and you will see I have written hundreds of quality answers if given the chance, as have many others.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that liquid smoke is carbon-based. Is the question you intended to ask something like "What unsmoked foods taste smoked?"?

Comment: I've got to agree with @SAJ14SAJ. Are you looking to remove the meat completely or just use non-smoked meat and add smokiness through another means?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the meat completely, many "meat replacements" like tempeh and tofu are available in smoked varieties.  Most of these simply have liquid smoke AKA "Natural Smoke Flavoring" added as part of their process, but actual smoked varieties do exist.

Smoky flavors can also be attained from the following

- Freshly roasted cumin
- Spanish style smoked paprika
- Chipotle or other smoked chiles
- [Liquid Smoke](http://www.colgin.com/liquid-smoke.php)
- Some porters, stouts, and especially rauchbiers
- Lapsang Souchong tea
- Smoked salt
- Katsuobushi/Bonito flakes (also adds a distinct fish flavor)